# JSF:pass real locale parameter to resourceBundle call instead of default null

Tags: jsf, parameters, locale, resourcebundle

There is quit non-trivial menu on UI.
Its items named in loop this way:

loop start

```
<li>
<h:commandLink action="#{menuItem.getGlobalTransitionName()}">#{resourceBundle.getMessage(menuItem.id,null,menuItem.id,null)}
</h:commandLink>
</li>
```

loop end

call to resourceBundle performed above,where default locale is set - it's hardcoded to `null` value,so resolved to `En` always:

```
#{resourceBundle.getMessage(menuItem.id,null,menuItem.id,null)}
```

What I've tried:

**1.** this invokes parsing error:

```
#{resourceBundle.getMessage(menuItem.id,null,menuItem.id,${externalContext.locale})}
```

**2.** this invokes error as well:

```
#{resourceBundle.getMessage(menuItem.id,null,menuItem.id,#{resourceBundle.locale})}
```

how can I pass really used locale there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting EL expressions is indeed invalid. Don't do that. Plus, `ExternalContext` doesn't have a `getLocale()` method. You want to use `#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}` instead.

```
#{resourceBundle.getMessage(menuItem.id,null,menuItem.id,facesContext.viewRoot.locale)}
```

Comment: I've used ${externalContext.locale} in our application and it works ok

Comment: Well, then it's implementation specific. The standard API at least definitely doesn't have that. There's only a `getRequestLocale()` method. See also http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html